# Get result from different tables - join

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have following tables in my DB

```
CREATE TABLE [author_details] (
[_id] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
[name] TEXT  NOT NULL,
[surname] TEXT  NOT NULL,
[middle_name] TEXT  NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [authors] (
[_id] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
[book_id] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[author_id] INTEGER  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [books] (
[_id] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
[title] TEXT  NOT NULL,
[publisher_id] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[isbn] VARCHAR(10)  UNIQUE NULL,
[ean] VARCHAR(13)  UNIQUE NULL,
[pages] INTEGER DEFAULT '0' NULL,
[year] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[edition] TEXT  NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [publishers] (
[_id] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
[name] TEXT  NOT NULL
);
```

I want a list of all books with details, I've used following query:

```
SELECT b.title,b.isbn,b.ean,b.year,b.pages,b.edition,
    CASE
        WHEN ad.middle_name IS NULL
            THEN ad.name||" "||ad.surname
            ELSE ad.name||" "||ad.middle_name||" "||ad.surname
    END AS author, p.name
FROM books AS b, authors AS a, author_details AS ad, publishers AS p
INNER JOIN authors, author_details, publishers ON b._id=a.book_id AND ad._id=a.author_id AND b.publisher_id=p._id
GROUP BY b._id
```

It returns All books but only one author for books with multiple authors. How to write the query to get all authors per book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values from all records in a group, you have to use the [group_concat](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) function:

```
SELECT b.title,b.isbn,b.ean,b.year,b.pages,b.edition,
       group_concat(CASE
                    ...
                    END) AS author, p.name
FROM ...
```

Additionally, you need to use the correct [join syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html).
In your query, you are joining every table twice, which results in lots up duplicate records.

There are two equivalent syntaxes for joins.
Either use a plain list of tables, and WHERE:

```
...
FROM books          AS b,
     authors        AS a,
     author_details AS ad,
     publishers     AS p
WHERE b._id          = a.book_id
  AND a.author_id    = ad._id
  AND b.publisher_id = p._id
...
```

or use the JOIN operator for each join, with a join condition for each join:

```
...
FROM books          AS b
JOIN authors        AS a  ON b._id          = a.book_id
JOIN author_details AS ad ON a.author_id    = ad._id
JOIN publishers     AS p  ON b.publisher_id = p._id
...
```

Comment: what is better with WHERE or with JOIN? both works :)

Comment: They are implemented identically. Use whatever is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [group_concat()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html):

```
SELECT b.title,b.isbn,b.ean,b.year,b.pages,b.edition,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE
        WHEN ad.middle_name IS NULL
            THEN ad.name||" "||ad.surname
            ELSE ad.name||" "||ad.middle_name||" "||ad.surname
    END) AS author, 
    p.name
FROM
.........
```

Comment: in SQL Administrator app it fails with no such method 'group_concat'. In the SQLite Database Browser app it works but the author contains multiple entries of the first author, followed by a series of 2nd author. "Rasmus Lerdorf,Rasmus Lerdorf,Rasmus Lerdorf,Rasmus Lerdorf,[...],Kevin Tatroe,Kevin Tatroe,Kevin Tatroe"

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela I'm not sure if SQLlite supports it but try to use DISTINCT -  `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE.....`

Comment: Use of DISTINCT has fixed my clumsy query so I'm voting up, but correct answer is from CL as he actually fixed my query.